# Directory contents into a spreadsheet entry

Tags: folders, numbers, automation

I would like to turn the contents of a folder into entries for Numbers (or Excel) - is there a way to automate doing this?

Comment: Just the filenames or addititional information (size, creation date etc) as well?

Comment: Just the filename is my immediate need - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Automator.app to create a service in finder.

Open Automator.

- Create a new service documents
- set the the service receives selected **Folders** in **Finder**
- Add a **Get folder contents** Action.
- Add a Get **Run Applescript** Action.
- replace the applescript content with the applescript below.

.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set theCsv to ""
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in input
        tell application "Finder" to set this_item to displayed name of item i of input
        set this_item to this_item & ",\\n"
        set theCsv to theCsv & this_item
    end repeat
    do shell script "echo " & quoted form of theCsv & " > ~/Desktop/names.csv"
end run
```

[image]

- save the document

Now when you select a folder in finder you can use the contextual menu to run the service on the folder.

It will create a .csv file on your desktop of the list. Which will open in Numbers.

Note: if you have more than one folder it will create a single list for both.
It is possible to have it only work on the first folder or both individually

---

UPDATE:

A quick applescript example to work on multiple folders in selection.
This will create a individual file for each directory in the finder selection

```
    on run {input, parameters}
        set theCsv to ""

        set pathList to {}
        repeat with i from 1 to number of items in input
            tell application "Finder" to set the Cpath to container of item i of input as alias
            if (Cpath as alias) is not in pathList then
                copy Cpath to end of pathList
            end if
        end repeat


        repeat with a from 1 to number of items in pathList
set this_item to item a of pathList
    set thisFileName to ""
        tell application "Finder" to set thisFileName to displayed name of (this_item as alias)

            set the CSVpath to ""
            repeat with i from 1 to number of items in input

                tell application "Finder"
                    set the Cpath to container of item i of input as alias

                    if container of item i of input as alias is this_item then
                        set theName to displayed name of item i of input & ",\\n"
                        set CSVpath to CSVpath & theName

                    end if
                end tell
            end repeat

     do shell script "echo " & quoted form of CSVpath & " > ~/Desktop/" & quoted form of thisFileName &  ".csv"
        end repeat


    end run
```

UPDATE 2.
This second example now uses the folder name as the name for the file

Comment: That is great and functional, is it possible to tweak the code so that the name of the output .csv is the same as the input folder name?

Comment: yes. give me a min

Comment: @EyeOjO , done (second example only)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (but somehow manual) way is to select all the files in Finder, copy them to the clipboard with <kbd>Cmd-C</kbd> and then pasting the names into a Numbers sheet with <kbd>Cmd-V</kbd>.

If you want more control, you can revert to Terminal for the *copy* step and run

```
cd /some/folder
ls *.jpeg | pbcopy
```

to get the name all jpeg files in this folder into the clipboard.